# Entity Framework 6: one-to-one relationship with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I'm using EF6 Code First and here's a simple model which reproduces my issue:

```
abstract class GeoInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double CoordX { get; set; }
    public double CoordY { get; set; }
}

class PersonGeoInfo : GeoInfo
{
    [Required]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

class CarGeoInfo : GeoInfo
{
    [Required]
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonGeoInfo PersonGeoInfo { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual CarGeoInfo CarGeoInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And a context:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GeoInfo> GeoInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonGeoInfo> PersonGeoInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarGeoInfo> CarGeoInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework generates this database:

[image: db schema]

Look at `GeoInfoes` foreign keys constraints. They both are in one column and using this database is imposible. But EF didn't warned me, it just throws database exception: `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY...`

I've tried to use TPT strategy - the same problem, but mixing is between association and inheritance keys.

I've tried to explicitly define foreign keys in model - didn't help. Nothing stops EF from generating a FK constraint in the same PK column.

I can't create a base class for a `Car` and a `Person` because in real app they are already participate in another hierarchies.

Am I using Entity Framework wrong or it really can't map one-to-one relationship along with inheritance to a database?

Comment: What do you need the `CarGeoInfo` and `PersonGeoInfo` for? The `PK, FK` is because of one-to-one relationship. If you want to have separate keys, remove the `virtual` properties from your `models`, this will generate `FK` columns in the `GeoInfo` table.

Comment: @Ghukas No, it will not

Comment: Why a TPT strategy does not adapt to your escenario?

Comment: Yes, it will, I've used the classes from your example without the `virtual` properties. EF has generated the Foreign Keys for both `Cars` and `People` entities. I'm using EF 6.1.2

Comment: @Ghukas It's strange, I've just tried it too. Can you provide full example code as an answer?

Comment: @octavioccl If TPT, the FK to the base class table mixing with the association FK in the same PK column. To enable TPT change my example by providing `TableAttribute` to a `PersonGeoInfo` and `CarGeoInfo`

Comment: @Ghukas Ah, I see what you mean. You want to delete to whole navigation property. I thought you want to remove `virtual` keyword. Yes, of course, no property - no problem =)

Comment: @Ghukas I need to be able to retrieve coordinates by person's or car's id, and to retrieve person or a car knowing the `GeoInfo.Id`

Comment: OK, what's the reason you do not want to use the Foreign Keys? Having the `ID` of the `GeoInfo`, you are always able to find the appropriate `Cars` and `Persons` by the generated Foreign Keys
http://i.imgur.com/TVTYaq1.png
The thing is now you have to use the relations as one-to-many, however there always will be one entity related.

Comment: @Ghukas Yeah, I've just understood that I don't need that nav props. Db will keep one-to-many relation, but EF can ensure it will be one-to-one using [Required] attribute. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can resolve your problem with this model:

```
public class GeoInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double CoordX { get; set; }
    public double CoordY { get; set; }

}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonGeoInfo")]
    public int? PersonGeoInfoId { get; set; }

    public virtual GeoInfo PersonGeoInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarGeoInfo")]
    public int? CarGeoInfoId { get; set; }

    public virtual GeoInfo CarGeoInfo { get; set; }
}
```

This way, a `Person` and a `Car` are  associated with a `GeoInfo`, and and when you want to find a person by their coordinates, you could do this:

```
 int geoInfoId = 3;
 var person=_db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.PersonGeoInfoId==geoInfoId);
```

But as you can see, with this model you are going to have one-to many relationships between `Person` and `GeoInfo` and `Car` and `GeoInfo`. I think this model could be more real because, eg, two people could have the same coordinates.

Comment: Well, in my case it's imposible to have two people at one `GeoInfo`, but in general, idea is right - we can go to a one-to-many relationships from one-to-zero-or-one